# Repeatedly asked for password smb share

Tags: networking, 16.04, nautilus, samba

I have a Samba share on my router that I access on several computers on the network. I have no problems accessing it on my Windows computer or my Ubuntu laptop (15.10), but when I try to connect on my Ubuntu desktop (16.04) I am repeatedly greeted by the username and password dialog. If memory serves me correctly, at one stage I was able to connect with this computer.

When I click connect I am shown the dialog again without being connected:
[image]

If I set the share to allow guest login I am able to access the share.

Is there anything that would be causing this, or any way to find out what the error is?

I don't think I have changed any settings, but if there is an easy way to return everything relevent to their defaults it would be good to try that.